# Google Maps/Google Earth - KML Overlays and Custom Orientation

Tags: kml, google, maps, mapping

I am am trying to get the floor plans for our various buildings imported into 4 separate KML files, one for each floor level so that I can toggle them with javascript. I'm able to overlay our floor plan images and properly scale them in Google earth, but once exported the KML doesn't display properly.

Please take note that whatever the orientation of the Google map is, I can't get my overlays to display properly. On the actual API based map, I have it set to be oriented with West at the top instead of North, which seemingly throws us another curve ball, as when I attempt to load the KML per the API's docs and refresh the API based map, I end up with nothing but "There are no images for this zoom level."

My KML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"     xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<GroundOverlay>
<name>Untitled Image Overlay</name>
<Icon>
    <href>http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/2600/walther.png</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
</Icon>
<LatLonBox>
    <north>37.21924494476235</north>
    <south>37.21876115002708</south>
    <east>-93.2637540015874</east>
    <west>-93.26445522810076</west>
    <rotation>87.56327787656277</rotation>
</LatLonBox>
```

My API v3 Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.22090,-93.26371),
            zoom: 18,
            minZoom: 18,
            maxZoom: 21,
            heading:-90,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

        //here's where it breaks!!!
        //it just won't load the kml...or it is and just breaks beyond reason!
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('test.kml');
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }  
</script>
```

Here's what it looks like in Google earth (correct):

http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/6348/gearth.jpg

Here's what it looks like in Google maps (for testing only, using it to load the KML...until I also figure out how to get my API based map to even display the layer without breaking):

http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/2237/gmapsr.jpg

Does anyone here have any idea what I need to do to get the display working properly, with regular google maps and more importantly my API based google map?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Limitations of KML/KMZ on Google Maps API:

Google Maps supports the following KML elements (that is, KML queries in the Search box and GGeoXml objects in the Maps API):

```
Placemarks
Icons
Folders
Descriptive HTML
    Entity replacement via <BalloonStyle> and <text> 
KMZ (compressed KML, including attached images)
Polylines and polygons
Styles for polylines and polygons, including color, fill, and opacity
Network links to import data dynamically
Ground overlays and screen overlays
```

This list does not apply to Google Earth's export to Google Maps, My Maps import, or My Maps export to Google Earth.

**The KML parser generally silently ignores XML tags it does not understand.**

Google Maps currently has specific limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits:

Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any time.
Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  3MB
Maximum uncompressed KML file size  10MB
Maximum number of Network Links 10
Maximum number of total document-wide features  1,000

Comment: You need to have 4 different images for the rotation to work on the Google Maps API. or use http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: I shouldn't have to make a different image for each zoom level and direction, now should I? If this is the case, is there an example somewhere? This is a real pain!

Comment: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://www.evangel.edu/apps/test/matt/map/test.xml
Line Number 18, Column 2:</xml>
-^

Comment: That's actually fixed, but ... still nothing.

Comment: Seems to me that when the map is oriented with West facing up on the screen, that gmaps forces the 45 degree angle and won't display overlays.

Comment: I know what your trying to achieve but I have never seen an example of it live - I think it is unsupported in Google Maps API - but can be done in Google Earth.

Comment: Well, I guess I could make the maps div larger, flip it with javascript, build my own controls, and just use the flipped version of the flat map.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have in your KML file, the [rotation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#rotation) tag, which explicity rotate the shape almost 90°.

You should try removing it and you will get the expected result!

Comment: Close but not quite...I've been playing with that. I've got it working on my API based map (had to put the KML in a public viewable location)..

I'm using the 45 degree view as it's the only view I have for this location if I want West at the top of the map...

Comment: But still, overlays will NOT work on the 45 degree angle view for some reason.

Comment: have you tried to load your kml file directly in GMaps ? like that : http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://yourdomain.tld/your_kml_file.kml

Comment: Yes, I have. It seems the <rotation> tags are doing absolutely nothing...

Comment: may you provide the full kml to us to make some tests?

Comment: Sure - http://www.evangel.edu/apps/test/matt/map/test.xml

Comment: Also, the map itself is at http://www.evangel.edu/apps/test/matt/map/ ...I'm revamping our campus map.

Comment: ...it actually centers properly when I don't include the KML as well, I assume that's another tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using a [GroundOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) object in javascript instead of a KML. Maybe this will give you better results.

[Here's an example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html)

```js
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.716216,-74.213393),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.765641,-74.139235));

var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    "http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg",
    imageBounds);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually tried that and it doesn't work.